# Weighted limit calculus

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, weights

In [coend calculus](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02503.pdf) by Fosco Loregian, it is mentioned that Lawvere conjectured that co/ends constitute a categorification of logical calculus. In his own words:

> The somewhat far-fetched conjecture that permeates all the book is that coend calculus provides an higher-dimensional version of a deductive system, suited for category theory (see [CW01] for some preliminary steps in this direction), having deduction rules similar to those of Gentzen’s sequent calculus. We will never attempt to turn this enticing conjecture into a theorem, or even to make a precise claim; the interested reader is thus warned that their curiosity will not get satisfaction –not in the present book, at least. We record that the idea that coends categorify logical calculus comes from William Lawvere, and it was first proposed in [Law73].

I'm curious to what extent this view on co/ends has been explored, but I'm also curious about the way Loregian discusses co/ends as having a 'richer computational structure' than mere limits and colimits. He argues that, for example, they allow for things like abstract deductive-style arguments establishing when two objects of a category are isomorphic if one of the objects is a coend (c.f. p. iii in the above notes).

This is interesting given the fact that co/ends themselves are special cases of weighted limits (and vice-verse) -- for a functor $F:\mathcal{C}^{op}\times \mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$, the end of $F$ 'is' the weighted limit $$\varprojlim_{{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,-)}F$$ where ${\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,-)$ is the hom-functor for $\mathcal{C}$ (valued in ${\bf Set}$ for a standard category or $\mathcal{V}$ for a $\mathcal{V}$-enriched category), which should mean that weighted limits also admit a 'calculus' with stronger deductive properties than standard limits/colimits admit. But then we have the fact that any weighted limit in a standard category is equivalent to a conical one -- this is not the case for enriched/two-dimensional categories, so perhaps therein lies the extra expressive power. Irrespective, my question is

> Has there been any work done on a 'weighted limit calculus' in the sense discussed above?

Any references or assistance are appreciated.

Comment: I am working on that!

Comment: I suppose this doesn't rise to the level of a "formal system", but weighted co/limits are used pretty systematically in Kelly's [Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html) for example. In general, Kan extensions, co/ends, co/limits, weighted co/limits -- they're all basically inter-definable and have similar expressive power. As Mac Lane says, "All concepts are Kan extensions".

Comment: Also possibly of interest in the more formal direction are [clubs of mixed variance](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/club#clubs_of_mixed_variance) and Kelly's [many-variable functorial calculus](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0059556).

Comment: @fosco Glad to hear it! Thank you for the references Tim, I’ll give them a look.